# Large Amplitude Oscillation Period Approximation

Tags: classical-mechanics, oscillators

When the amplitude of pendulum oscillation is large (beyond 20 degree), the function for the period of the oscillation is shown in the picture below;

[image]

The question: **How many terms** do you think would be required for the approximation to give a good value for the case where the amplitude equals **3.0 rad**? (172 degree) (Say, the error less than 1% is a good approximation)

I have tried finding the limit of the infinite sequence online but failed. (Maybe I didn't use good search terms?) I have also tried to restrict the last term of the least terms required, but didn't know what value to use to restrict that last term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum consists of two factors
\begin{align}
T/T_0 - 1 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_1(n) \cdot f_2(n)
\\
f_1(n) &= \left(
\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n n!}
\right)^2
\\
f_2(n) &= \big(\sin(A/2)\big)^{2n} = q^{n}
\end{align}
Both factors are smaller than 1. Hence,  if we stop after the $p^{th}$ term the error can be estimated by
$
\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty f_1(n) \cdot f_2(n)
\le 
f_1(p+1) \sum_{n=p+1}^\infty  f_2(n)
= f_1(p+1) \sum_{n=p+1}^\infty q^{n}
$. The sum is a geometric series, for which a solution is known. Hence, although it might be impossible to estimate the exact error, we can easily state an upper limit or generate a solution such that the error is smaller than 1%.